# Use Bus.Send (not Publish) from web applications (NServiceBus v3.2.0.0)

Tags: nservicebus, nservicebus3

We have an asp.net mvc3 application which **publishes** a number of events. Recently, someone pointed out that we should be **sending** messages rather than publishing events from the web application and referenced this [excellent blog post](http://www.make-awesome.com/2010/10/why-not-publish-nservicebus-messages-from-a-web-application/) which makes perfect sense. However, I want to confirm that the points made in the post are still valid for NServiceBus v3.x?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would imagine that the reasoning behind the post would always hold true, irrespective of the version of NServiceBus.

That being said, there is nothing stopping you from publishing a message from a web-site.  The idea behind publishing a message is that the message represents an event that is typically produced by some *processing* endpoint.  Since a web application should not really be processing anything but rather be *sending* commands off to a processing endpoint it would stand to reason that a web application should not be publishing events.

So if you find yourself in a situation where it seems to make sense to publish from your web application it indicates that you need to make a design decision: either the design is not optimal (so the web application is performing processing) *or* you are constrained in some way the prohibits the implementation of a processing endpoint (maybe a shared hosting environment).